# Power Supply for PI Zero

Tags: power, power-supply, usb-power, pi-zero, power-management

I was thinking about getting a cable for Pi Zero, this one:
https://www.adafruit.com/products/1995

But it's 2.4 ampere, won't that overcharge the little Pi Zero and damage it?

The specifications say that:
DC OUTPUT VOLTAGE RANGE MAX 5.36V (+/- 5%)

And the 5% extra is a bit worrying that is already 5.628 V, whereas the maximum tolerance of the Pi Zero is 6 volts, according to the website. That is very close.

---

So is it safe to use that power supply with Pi Zero, or should I just use the 1 Ampere official power supply?

Comment: Hello and welcome. I think the linked duplicate answers the issue.

Comment: Answering the voltage concern, it sounds that your power supply is guaranteed never to exceed those 5.63V, in which case it's far enough from 6 volts, so I wouldn't worry about it. But I agree it's a bit higher than typical supply voltage, which is between 5 and 5.25V.

Comment: @Ghanima Why is this question marked as duplicate? The duplicate was referring to RASPBERRY PI 2, not ZERO.

Comment: The issue is not about the Pi2 or the Zero, the issue you raise is about *too much current* - and there is no such thing. That's answered both here and at the linked question. Duplicate rules apply if the same answer addresses both questions. Same issue, same answer, dupe. Either way KennetRunner's answer and the answers/comments over at the other question should give you the advice you seek.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because it **can** supply 2.4 Amps doesn't mean it will. The Raspberry Pi Zero will draw what it needs to operate and no more. (unless you create a short circuit somewhere...)

There's a great [table/matrix here](http://raspi.tv/2015/raspberry-pi-zero-power-measurements) that lists what version draws what power under various circumstances.

Having a supply that is able to supply more (than 1 Amp) is useful if you are adding power supping accessories like WiFi dongles etc.

Comment: But if I add, say an extra device that will draw 1 more amper. So I have like 200 mA for the Pi zero, like 600 mA for the monitor, and another 1 A, for another device. That would be like 1.8 A, will that be ok? I know that the 2.4 amper is the maximum, but won't the PI Zero's circuits get damaged under that much ampers?